# HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp

I keep getting the following error:
HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

when trying to build on my local machine using google app engine.
The code in ShowJSPServlet.java file:

```
package helloJSP;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloJSPServlet  extends HttpServlet 
{
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException 
    {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");
    }
}
```

My web.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ShowJSP</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>helloJSP.ShowJSPServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ShowJSP</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ShowName</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>hello.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

The hello.jsp file contents are:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="mainform" method="post" action="/ShowName">
            <div>
                Name: <input id="url" type="text" size="100"/>
                <input type="submit" id="gobtn" value="Go" style="width: 70px"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the first time I am developing in JSP technology. What am I missing?

Comment: Two things. 1)How do you call Servlet ? 2) `public class  extends HttpServlet ` you are missing class name here.

Comment: @HardikMishra 
1) I have given the hello.jsp file contents
2) Updated it with the class name, but it still fails

Answer (score 1):

One problem is in your web.xml:

```
    <servlet-class>helloJSP.ShowJSPServlet</servlet-class>
```

should be

```
    <servlet-class>helloJSP.HelloJSPServlet</servlet-class>
```

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me try that